# gunzip from stdin

Tags: shell, gzip

I have a large collection of gz files. I want to extract them all. Here is what I was trying to do:

`find . | grep .gz | gunzip`

However, gunzip does not accept list of files from stdinput. How can I decompress them all(in place)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If what you are after is to call `gunzip` on every file with a name
ending in `.gz` anywhere within your current directory, this should do
it:

```
find . -type f -name '*.gz' exec gunzip {} +
```

The more general way to turn what is on standard input into arguments
to a command is to use xargs, but there are a few gotchas to be aware
of with that command.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a better approach would be to use `find`'s `-name` and `-exec` options? This way grep would be unnecessary, and it could hand each matching file to `gunzip`, individually.

This would look something like:

```
find . -name '*.gz' -exec gunzip '{}' +
```

All files within the `$CWD` (including within subdirectories), with names ending in `.gz` would be handed to `gunzip` for decompression. Also, the decompressed files would end up in the `$CWD` without taking further measures.

Comment: Good tip, unless the set of files found would result in a command line length error.

Comment: It wouldn't. If the limit is reached, `find` will break up the command, just like `xargs` does but minus the quoting issues.